# MySQL, 'SELECT' columns FROM 3 different Tables in same database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull info from three separate tables. Two appear have related primary keys and two appear to have related foreign keys. I have tried many different varieties of `JOIN` statements, alas to no avail. I need to select;

`order_date . .  order_time . . order_id . . item_id . . item_qty . . item_name . . menu_type . . item_name . . item_cost`

From these tables;

**ITEMS**

```
<p>order_id (primary key)</p>
<p>item_id (foreign key)</p>
<p>item_qty</p>
```

**ORDER**

```
<p>order_id (primary key</p>
<p>order_date</p>
<p>order_time</p>
```

**MENU**

```
<p>item_id (primary key)</p>
<p>menu_type</p>
<p>item_name</p>
<p>item_cost</p>
<p>item_month</p>
```

Any help would be be appreciated more than words here could express!Iv been at this for hours. Thank you!

Yes I just need the results from the query to output.

*Edit I have tried this and similar -

`SELECT ORDER.order_date, ORDER.order_time, ITEMS.order_id, ITEMS.item_id, ITEMS.item_qty, MENU.item_name, MENU.item_cost, MENU.menu_type 
FROM 'ORDER' INNER JOIN 'ITEMS' ON ORDER.order_id = ITEMS.order_id INNER JOIN 'MENU' ON MENU.item_id = ITEMS.item_id ORDER BY order_id;`

o.k. thanks for all your help guys. This was my first post so, sorry about the

tags. could't seem to list the tables any other way at first. Anyway - thank you for all your help.

Cheers.

Comment: based on what you want the output ?

Comment: show us your failed efforts. how did you try the `join`s?

Comment: Apart from the quotes around the table names I see nothing wrong with your select statement. Anyway, you should always say what problems you face. Syntax errors? Too many / too few / wrong results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL change `'` to `.

```
SELECT `ORDER`.order_date, `ORDER`.order_time, `ITEMS`.order_id, `ITEMS`.item_id, `ITEMS`.item_qty, `MENU`.item_name, `MENU`.item_cost, `MENU`.menu_type 
FROM `ORDER` INNER JOIN `ITEMS` ON `ORDER`.order_id = `ITEMS`.order_id INNER JOIN `MENU` ON `MENU`.item_id = `ITEMS`.item_id ORDER BY `ORDER`.order_id;
```

And in `ORDER BY` in field `order_id` put your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from menu m, order o, items i 
where m.item_id=i.item_id and i.order_id=o.order_id
```

add another where clause based on what you want the result